# Is it possible to hide a txtfile canonical menu entry in explorer (in this case, edit)

Tags: windows-explorer, shell, windows-registry

I have been working with the explorer menus since '95 to include authoring shell extensions in 'c/c++'.  I say this because I *believe* that I already understand how the file association keys work.

My problem is that I don't want `Edit` on the right click of txt files and there IS NO KEY that I can see (Edit *appears* to be a canonical verb).  Perhaps there is a new place in the registry that per user entries can be used to amend this?  Btw, I can remove `Open` and `Print` just fine.. only not ***EDIT*** because it isn't there!

I have created sub-menus to hold my plethora of editors and the additional "Edit" is just annoying.

To save everyone the trouble.. a couple of pictures are worth a couple of thousand words.

[image]

[image]

I am assuming that this functionality is hardcoded into the explorer for some reason.  I hope that I am wrong.

Also.. I know that I could write a shell extension to edit the menu at runtime but not for this.. I will simply ignore it.

> Help me Obi Wan Explorer Guru Kenobi.  You are my only hope.

Comment: Been a while since I messed with menu entries, but iirc there was the 'type' and the extension itself, and both combined populate the menu entries. Do you also have a .txt key with defined menu entries? And if so, is 'edit' perhaps specified there? i.e. Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.txt

Comment: Worth a shot :) Another suggestion: If you can figure out what the associated command for the 'edit' menu entry is, you could perhaps just do a full registry search. Yes, that takes ages, but I assume the culprit is hiding in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, so that reduces the search area a bit.

Comment: And another suggestion: see what kind of associations there are with NirSoft's FileTypesMan. That should also allow you to directly remove that 'edit' entry. https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/file_types_manager.html

Comment: @MiG !!  YOU GOT IT! (DING DING DING) .. there ***IS*** a new set of keys I didn't know about but NirSoft DID! (and I will from now on).  FYI, the "extra keys" I couldn't see are in `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\BLAHBLAHBLAH`.  If you want to answer this, I will give you the points.

Comment: Excellent :) I'm a bit sleepy so I've kept it short. If I should add more feel free to comment :)

Comment: FYI: `HKCR\SystemFileAssociations\...` contains entries that will be displayed for a given file type *regardless* of what program has been selected to open the type.

Comment: I forgot to comment.  Thank you @KeithMiller for that last tidbit. :)

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas You're welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [NirSoft's File Types Manager](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/file_types_manager.html) to see what menu items are associated with a given extension, and edit them directly. FileTypesMan pools together the relevant reg keys and therefore saves you a lengthy registry search.

For txt files, locations for menu entries in explorer can be:

- `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.txt (file type)`
- `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\txtfile (perceived type)`
- `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\.txt (default file type)`
- `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\text (default perceived type)`

**'Edit' menu entry**

The mysterious 'edit' command can be found here:

- `Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\text\shell\edit`

**SystemFileAssociations key**

> Subkeys registered under HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations enable the Shell to define the default behavior of attributes for file types and enable shared file associations. When users change the default application for a file type, the ProgID of the new default application has priority in providing verbs and other association information. This priority is due to it being the first entry in the association array. If the default program is changed, the information under the previous ProgID is no longer available.

Source: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/app-registration

**HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT key**

Note that depending on the situation, edits in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT will land at either one of these keys:

- `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes`
- `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes`

> To change the default settings, store the changes under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes. If you write keys to a key under HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, the system stores the information under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes. If you write values to a key under HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, and the key already exists under HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes, the system will store the information there instead of under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes.

Source: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/hkey-classes-root-key

Comment: It would be awesome if you would also add the key that I didn't know about.  That was my REAL problem and this tool helped me come to that conclusion.  Thanks again MiG.

Comment: Expanded it a bit, hope this helps :)